# Scope is not being applied to the scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I have this snippet of code in my controller:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
$scope.nodeId = $stateParams.studynodeRef;
  Studies.fetchCollection($scope.nodeId).then(function(data){
      $scope.y = angular.fromJson(data.list);
      $scope.collections = angular.fromJson($scope.y[0].collections);
      console.log($scope.collections);
})
});
```

The reason I have $scope.$on is because I want the nodeId to update every time I enter the view so it can update the collections. Now before I had the $scope.$on function and just had the Study.fetchCollection function I was able to iterate through collections in my template like this:

```
 <ion-list ng-controller="StudyCtrl">
      <ion-item ng-repeat="collection in collections" nav-clear menu-close ng-click="go('app.studies')" class="item item-icon-left brand-base-text-color">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-paper"></i>
            {{collection.name}}
        </ion-item>
```

But now it displays nothing. Even if I just try to display {{collections}} it shows nothing. The console returns $scope.collections as a list of objects but I don't think the $scope is being applied which is why {{collections}} is blank and I am not sure how to use $scope.$apply() in this context. I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to fix this

Comment: But have you tried to use $scope.$apply() already? $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.collections = angular.fromJson($scope.y[0].collections);
        });

Comment: I tried same now I get a $digest already in progress error

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to overcome this is to create a function and call in within the controller and since the controller is attached to the view it will get updated every time you enter the view . Something like this

```
$scope.onLoad = function() {
    $scope.nodeId = $stateParams.studynodeRef;
    Studies.fetchCollection($scope.nodeId).then(function(data){
        $scope.y = angular.fromJson(data.list);
        $scope.collections = angular.fromJson($scope.y[0].collections);
        console.log($scope.collections);
    })
}
$scope.onLoad();
```

Comment: Right but see the thing I want the controller or well the fetchCollection to load every time I access that same view. I understand that the controller for the view is only loaded once unless you refresh the page. Which is why I was using $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function()